# Aliens placed humans on Earth to become starship engineers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, spaceship

Please help me identify this SF short story.

What I remember:
Several characters at a party.  All of the attendees are very intelligent.  One of the guests poses a hypothetical question about how someone would go about breeding humans to become starship engineers.

The party guests develop a scheme.  Then all the guests including the one asking the question get whisked away.  The guests are broken into groups and dispersed among several habitable planets in other star systems.

As a joke, the person who asked the question (who we now know was an alien breeding for starship engineers) rolled a huge chocolate coin candy down the hill to one group of smart people.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I remember that. It was a short story by Larry Niven called "What Can You Say About Chocolate Covered Manhole Covers?" It was in the book "All the Myriad Ways" and reprinted in N-Space.

Comment: Wow, I'm a huge Niven fan and read most of his works.  I would never have associated it with him.